# Using MapReduce/Aggregation to create search facets

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo

I have the documents of the following prototype:

```
{
   title: "HD8200 DLP Projector",
   normal_price: 4999.99,
   specifications: [
       {
           ov: "HD (1920 x 1080)",
           fn: "Resolution (Native / Max)",
           o: 7,
           f: 211
       },
       {
           ov: "20000",
           fn: "Contrast Ratio",
           o: 15,
           f: 225
       }
   ]
}
```

I'm looking to create a list of filters for this product database, based on the specifications.

**How can I get a list of option IDs (`o`) mapped to their product counter, for each field (`f`)?**

Let's assume I need to achieve this for a specific list of field IDs (say, 211 and 225).

Answer (score 0):

Write a mapper to take one document per map() call and write out a record for each option.  The record key would be the field ID and the value would be a concatenation of a flag "1", the product title and option ID.

Write another mapper to read the list of id's and to write out a record with the same format: the key is the field ID and the value is a concatenation of a flag "0" and two empty strings.

Write a Reducer to read in the records written by the two mappers.  Each call to reducer() will pass in all records written for a given field.  If one of those records has a "0" flag then that field was one of the fields you're interested in.  Only then would you write out a record for each record with a "1" flag.  The key is the product title and the value is the option id.

Define your first job driver class to use the two mappers and the one reducer. This step will come up with pairs of product-options for the field id's you specify.  You'll need a second job to gather the options by product, or vide versa.